# Problem in logging my Yahoo! account

Tags: account-management, yahoo-mail, yahoo-account

For the past three days, I have been unable to access my Yahoo! Mail account. The following is displayed upon each login attempt:

> "It seems that we can't recover your account online. Please visit our help site to get back in."

I contacted Yahoo! Customer Care but noone has responded yet. Can anyone suggest a remedy to this issue or a way to recover my account rapidly?

Answer (score 2):

Use [Yahoo! Help](https://io.help.yahoo.com/contact/index?page=contact&locale=en_US&y=PROD_ACCT#) or create a new case through [Yahoo! Case Creation Form](https://io.help.yahoo.com/contact/index?y=PROD_ACCT&page=contactform&locale=en_US&token=Zh%2FBBVqXzLHlIbokbUqVWTUbuuQeXGkGnZzhKR2JQ4O6mMQdy9JSWfJCJWvc4C3%2F4ml2UKrHQ0nko7rLtSR524NwvUtZOo0Gj805mARbzr8vfgnNVTA8e9O5KtKpyg0HCTiJHUPMwrZY3nJcM3QshA45uqklXHRB&selectedChannel=email-icon&yid=) to verify and prove yourself as the owner of the locked account and submit it.

Allow 24 hours to 1 week upon the submission before you get a response.